# Firebase: any way to define a "any" node?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Ok, so this is what my Fireabse database looks like:

[image]
Now I need to update the "about" node for every user. Without the user node, this is what I would do:

```
    val mAllUserDatabase : DatabaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users"))

    val childUpdates = HashMap<String, Any>()
    childUpdates["/about"] = "new value"

    mAllUserDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates)
```

The problem is, I need to define the node of the user (don't I?). But since the user node all have a different name, I would need something like "any- node" or "all nodes". Something like

```
    childUpdates["/any/about"] = "new value"
```

or `getChildren()`of the snapshots.

What would be the best way to solve this? Do I have to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to read the names of all nodes and then use the names on `mAllUserDatabase` with `.updateChildren(childUpdates)`? That cant be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your `about` property within all user objects, please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val usersRef = rootRef.child("Users")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val childUpdates = HashMap<String, Any>()
            childUpdates["about"] = "yourNewAboutValue"
            ds.ref.updateChildren(childUpdates)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Answer (score 1):

To write a value to a node in the Firebase Realtime Database you need to know the exact path to that node. Firebase does not have the concept of SQL's update queries.

So in your case you'll need to first read the nodes you want to update, then loop over them, and then update them either one by one or with one big multi-location update statement.